# How to change icon of a leaflet marker when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a model that only appears when a marker is clicked. Inside of that marker cointains some information and three buttons (aceitar, recusar,concluido) when one of those buttons is clicked, the icon of the marker changes. The code that I have right now doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't do what's expected. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
var clickedmarker = null;

  $.get("/api/IgnicoesAPI", function (data) {

        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {

            //identificação do tipo de marcador que deve aparecer de acordo com o estado da ignição
            var ignicao;

            if (item.estado == "aceite") {
                ignicao = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: '/icons/aceite.png',
                    iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
                });
            }
            else {

                if (item.estado == "em avaliação") {
                    ignicao = L.icon({
                        iconUrl: '/icons/emAvaliacao.png',
                        iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
                    });
                }
                else {
                    if (item.estado == "concluido") {
                        ignicao = L.icon({
                            iconUrl: '/icons/concluido.png',
                            iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
                        });
                    }
                }
            }





            //colocar um marcador no mapa de acordo com a latitude e longitude fornecidas
            var marker = new L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude], { icon: ignicao })

                .on('click', function onClick(e) {

                    var id = item.id;

                    clickedmarker = e.target;

                    modal.style.display = "block";

                    getData(id);
                })

                .addTo(map);

            //adiciona marador ao mapa
            $('#json map').append(marker);
        });// fim each
    });//fim do get
```

The function getData contains the buttons that are going to be added to a div, taht only appears when the marker is clicked:

```
function getData(id) {

    $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`, function (data) {

        //o div terá que ser limpo para que a informação não seja subreposta
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = "";

        //Indicação do id e do estado da ignição clicada 
        $('#myDiv').append('<h3><b>Avaliação da Ignição</b></h3>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<p>Estado:' + data.estado + '</p>')
        $('#myDiv').append('<p>ID: ' + id + '</p>');

        $.each(data.listaOcorrencias, function (o, ocorrencia) {
            //é adicionado as imagens correspondente a cada ocorrencia pertecentes á ignição clicada
            $('#myDiv').append('<img src="imagensFogos/' + ocorrencia.fotografia + '" onclick="openModal();" class="hover-shadow" style="width:200px; height:190px" hspace="4"/>');

        });

        //adição dos botões que alteram o estado da ignição
        $('#buttons').append('<button id="aceite" onclick="aceite('+ id +')" style="background-color:#4CAF50;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); margin:5px;">Aceitar</button>');
        $('#buttons').append('<button id="recusado" onclick="recusado('+ id +')" style="background-color:#f44336;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);margin:5px;">Recusar</button>');
        $('#buttons').append('<button id="concluido" onclick="concluido('+ id +')" style="background-color:#008CBA;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);margin:5px;" > Concluído</button>');

    });
}
```

Here is the code of one of the buttons:

```
 function aceite(idmarcador) {
    console.log(clickedmarker);
    var accepted = L.icon({
        iconSize: [35, 35],
        iconUrl: 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transportation-icons-rounded/110/Fire-Truck-2-512.png'
    });
    //se um marcador for selecionado e não é null
    if (clickedmarker) { 
        //o icon desse marcador é selecionado
        clickedmarker.setIcon(accepted);   
    }
    clickedmarker = null;
    modal.style.display = "none";
   // atualizaBD(idmarcador, "aceite");
    connection.invoke("PostMarker").catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    //notificar a base de dados
}
```

Here is my console after I click a button (the arrow points to when button is clicked):

[image]

apperantly the data load again, and that's why the icon doesn't change. I'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: In function aceite, console.log accepted after you've made the call to L.icon ... anything? Inside of the if (clickedmarker) block, console.log clickedmarker ... anything? If console does show an object for clickedmarker, does it have a setIcon method?

Comment: Yes it does. But I think this isn't working bacause after the button is clicked the icon changes for a second but then changes back to how it was before. I'm not sure why

Comment: I think that the button click event is bubbling to the marker element, which has also has a click handler. Perhaps move your icon creation call to a higher scope.

Comment: it gives me errors if i do that

Comment: Move var accepted to a higher scope. Inside of marker.on("click"), call clickedmarker.setIcon(accepted) after clickedmarker = e.target; ... don't call setIcon in your button code

Comment: It kind of works, but it doesn't replace the privious one. And I have three buttons which means that deppending on the button that i clik I'll have different icons for each one of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208291/discussion-between-ted-fitzpatrick-and-teresa-alves).

Comment: Hi Teresa, I looked at Leaflet’s documentation and it looks like you need to use Leaflet’s handler api. I think the issue is accessing the marker dom element vs leaflet’s objects: https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html